# npm throws EACCES error on installation of Angular CLI

Tags: angular-cli, npm-install

I am unable to install Angular Cli globally through npm.
I keep getting this error when I run `npm install -g @angular/cli` on macOS:

```
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/apple/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: you are trying to install a module globally, in order to do that you need to do it with higher privileges, run `npm install -g angular-cli` as the `root` user - `sudo npm install -g angular-cli`

Comment: For those who get the same error, and those who copied a repo with .node folder in it! remove .node folder before installing!

Comment: I have removed the node modules folder and tried npm install. It worked. Thanks Diana.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When you use `npm install -g` on any platform and you get `EACCES`, you are writing to a directory for which you do not have write permission.

Some may recommend using `sudo`, but this will lead to more problems in the future. The [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) provides options to fix this.

I highly recommend [using a node version manager like nodenv](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally#reinstall-npm-with-a-node-version-manager) as the solution.

Comment: This was a great answer. Following the steps provided in the npm documentation link, I was able to solve the problem. (I removed an existing node, and reinstalled it through nvm as it was recommended)

Answer (score 24):

Try using this:
On the command line, in your home directory, create a directory for global installations:

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global
```

Configure npm to use the new directory path:

```
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
```

In your preferred text editor, open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

```
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

On the command line, update your system variables:

```
source ~/.profile
```

Test installing package globally without using sudo. 
Now run `npm install -g @angular/cli` it should work.

Comment: Step 3 says to `Open or create a ~/.profile file` - can you explain how to do this part?

Comment: This will create an empty profile file:  touch ~/.profile

Answer (score 7):

1. create a directory for global installations:

   `mkdir ~/.npm-global`
2. Configure npm to use the new directory path:

   `npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`
3. create a `~/.profile` file
4. add this line to your new `~/.profile` file:

   `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`
5. update your system variables:

   `source ~/.profile`

Reference: [Resolving EACCES permissions errors when installing packages globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)

Answer (score 6):

**WARNING: Check that `$(npm config get prefix)` does not point to `/usr` by typing `echo $(npm config get prefix)`**

I solved like that

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
```

Worked for me

Comment: Thank goodness. Other fixes didn't help me, so I guess it had to be changing ownership of the whole usr/local directory. Anyway. You legend!

Comment: that is a really bad idea. You shouldn't change the ownership of /bin /share

Comment: This wrecked my system (no access to sudo or su anymore), **do not use this**!! To revert, I had to login to a recovery shell and issue "sudo chown -R root /usr/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}".

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue by running

sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

After prompting for password enter it.

Then you will be able to install.

Answer (score 1):

This was a great link for me.

https://flaviocopes.com/npm-fix-missing-write-access-error/

once I did this command

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

in my terminal, the angular CLI install worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on Linux, where the repository was on a partition that was mounted with option `noexec`. Remounting the partition with `exec` solved it for me.

I had installed node through nvm, which is the recommended way to avoid permission issues. But if nvm can't execute in your folder, it won't work in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Ayush is what I tried at first. Yet the problem persisted. Maybe I didn't do all the steps correctly , I am not sure. So again I looked up Google and found this link https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7735#issuecomment-345546822. There are two ways to go about solving it. Luckily the first way worked for me. The step that might have made a difference may be compared to what Ayush mentioned above in the answers:

```
$ echo -e "export PATH=$(npm prefix -g)/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc 
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

I am using Ubuntu though! Anyways it is solved now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Then it will work, mine was also not working, but it worked with sudo.

Answer (score -1):

Hello Please Follow my guide to install angular 4 from the cli without any permission issues:

Install the `angular-cli` globally

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Create a new project

```
ng new my-app --skip-install
```

Serve the application

```
sudo chown <username> -R my-app
cd my-app
mkdir node_modules
chmod a+w node_modules
npm install
ng serve --open
```

Comment: sudo is not recommended

Answer (score -1):

EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/nod code example
Example 1: Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'

sudo npm install -g nodemon
//easiest fix

Example 2: npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng' -> '/usr/bin/ng'
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules

Comment: Please format your answer and clarify it, it is very unclear as the text is all together and it is not clear if this is an actual answer or you have an error.

Answer (score -1):

**

> Don't worry!!

**
Just use command form Root user like
Ex -

1. developer@developer:~$ sudo su
2. root@developer:/# npm install -g
   @angular/cli@11

And All Set