# How to solve EPERM: operation not permitted error in angular?

Tags: angular-cli

I am not able to install **npm install primeng --save, npm install file uploader**.
I tried npm cache clean --force but it did not worked out for me. Can anyone give the solution for this error?

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path E:\Nandhini\MetroLogin\node_modules\__ngcc_entry_points__.json
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'E:\Nandhini\MetroLogin\node_modules\__ngcc_entry_points__.json'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'E:\Nandhini\MetroLogin\node_modules\__ngcc_entry_points__.json'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'E:\\Nandhini\\MetroLogin\\node_modules\\__ngcc_entry_points__.json'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dev.NRajkumar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-17T08_42_20_486Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I have the same problem in linux. The file gets created by the 'root' user so my user doesn't have permission to it. I tried changing the owner of "npm" and "node" to my user but that file is still created by the 'root' owner. whatever exe is creating that file needs to be owned by the current user, not root.

Comment: It is a permissions issue. Follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62946338/558509