# I am not able to install Angular/Cli onto my ubuntu 18 system

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu, npm, angular-cli

I am trying to install Angular/CLI onto my Ubuntu system.

> Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS 64 bit

```
 node -v


npm -v
```

npm version is **3.5.2**

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

I have installed Node and its showing version as **v8.10.0** but when I try to install Angular/cli It shows some error as below

```
 npm install -g @angular/cli
- |---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
WARN engine @angular/cli@9.0.2: wanted: {"node":">= 10.13.0","npm":">= 6.11.0","yarn":">= 1.13.0"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"3.5.2"})
WARN engine @angular/cli@9.0.2: wanted: {"node":">= 10.13.0","npm":">= 6.11.0","loadDep:uuid -> get       / |##########---------------------------------------|
WARN engine @angular-devkit/architect@0.900.2: wanted: {"node":">= 10.13.0","npmloadDep:uuid -> get       - |##########---------------------------------------|
WARN engine @angular-devkit/core@9.0.2: wanted: {"node":">= 10.13.0","npm":">= 6.11.0","yarn":">= 1.13.0"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"3.5.2"})
WARN engine @angular-devkit/schematics@9.0.2: wanted: {"node":">= 10.13.0","npm"loadDep:uuid -> get       | |##########---------------------------------------|
WARN engine @schematics/angular@9.0.2: wanted: {"node":">= 10.13.0","npm":">= 6.loadDep:uuid -> network   | |##########---------------------------------------|
WARN engine @schematics/update@0.900.2: wanted: {"node":">= 10.13.0","npm":">= 6npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular
/usr/local/lib
`-- @angular/cli@9.0.2 

npm ERR! Linux 5.3.0-28-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli'
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/sagar/npm-debug.log
sagar@sagar-HP-Notebook:~$ ng -v
Node.js version v8.10.0 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v10.13 or v12.0.


 ng -v

Node.js version v8.10.0 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v10.13 or v12.0.
```

Can anyone please help me to get rid of this error.

Comment: read this link, help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42042300/angular-cli-install-error/42042619

Comment: The error message clearly says wanted: {"node":">= 10.13.0","npm":">= 6.11.0"; your versions are way older. Just use a later node and npm.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your NodeJS version is not compatible with your Angular CLI version. See the `Angular CLI/Angular/NodeJS/Typescript` compatibility details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60258560/415078)

> Also I would recommend to use [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to manage NodeJS - this way you can switch between NodeJS versions with ease.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
  sudo npm cache clean --force
  sudo npm install --force -g @angular/cli
```

Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You have not write permission to create directory, try it with :

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: I used this command but`sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`

Still same issue

Comment: Node.js version v11.15.0 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v10.13 or v12.0.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem:

Solutions is simple:
Run the following commands one by one.

1. sudo npm cache clean -f
2. sudo npm install -g n
3. sudo n stable

after that run the following command to create your new project.

ng new <projectName>

if still having problem then simply close the terminal and open again.

you are good to go !!!!